# Dividing a cell number after finding the other cell number based on a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a `2000x20` excel file. Each cell in column B has a 6 digit number. I am interested in dividing cell value M when I have  `502000` in column B with cell value with column B `501000`. The rest of the row is same from A to H except B.

Right now I am using two for loops which takes 100sec to finish. I am looking for an efficient idea. Thanks in advance :)

```
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer

For a = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    For b = a To 2 Step -1

        If Cells(a, "A") = Cells(b, "A") And Cells(a, "B") = "502000" _
           And Cells(b, "B") = "501000" And Cells(a, "C") = Cells(b, "C") _
           And Cells(a, "D") = Cells(b, "D") And Cells(a, "E") = Cells(b, "E") _ 
           And Cells(a, "F") = Cells(b, "F") And Cells(a, "G") = Cells(b, "G") _ 
           And Cells(a, "H") = Cells(b, "H") Then 
             Cells(a, "P") = Cells(a, "L") / Cells(b, "L")
        end if
    Next b
Next a
```